# Remove text between one string and 1st occurrence of another string

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have found several solutions to remove text between two strings but I guess my case is a little different.

I am trying to convert this:

```
/nz/kit.7.2.0.7/bin/adm/tools/hostaekresume
```

To this:

```
/nz/kit/bin/adm/tools/hostaekresume
```

Basically remove the version specific information from the filename.
The solutions I have found remove everything from the word `kit` to the *last* occurrence of `/`. I need something to remove from `kit` to the *first* occurrence.

The most common solution I have seen is:

```
sed -e 's/\(kit\).*\(\/\)/\1\2/'
```

Which produces:

```
/nz/kit/hostaekresume
```

How can I only remove up to the *first* `/`? I assume this can done with sed or awk, but open to suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sed 's|\(kit\)[^/]*|\1|' <<< '/nz/kit.7.2.0.7/bin/adm/tools/hostaekresume'
/nz/kit/bin/adm/tools/hostaekresume
```

This uses a different delimiter (`|` instead of `/`) so we don't have to escape the `/`. Then, for non-greedy matching, it uses `[^/]*`: any number of characters *other than `/`*, which matches everything between `kit` and the next `/`.

Alternatively, if you know that what you want to remove consists of dots and digits, and nothing else in the string contains them, you can use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ var='/nz/kit.7.2.0.7/bin/adm/tools/hostaekresume'
$ echo "${var//[[:digit:].]}"
/nz/kit/bin/adm/tools/hostaekresume
```

The syntax is `${parameter/pattern/string}`, where `pattern` in the expanded `parameter` is replaced by `string`. If we use `//` instead of `/`, all occurrences instead of just the first are replaced.

In our case, `parameter` is `var`, the pattern is `[[:digit:].]` (digits or a dot – this is a glob pattern, not a regular expression, by the way), and we've skipped the `/string` part, which just removes the pattern (replaces it with nothing).

Answer (score 0):

You need `perl` for non-greedy regex. `sed` doesn't do that yet.
Also, use `|` as a delimiter since `/` can cause confusion when you have it in your regex.

`perl -pe 's|(kit).*?(/.*)|\1\2|'`

The `?` after the `.*` makes the pattern non-greedy and will match the first instance of `/`.

`echo "/nz/kit.7.2.0.7/bin/adm/tools/hostaekresume" | perl -pe 's|(kit).*?(/.*)|\1\2|'`
returns
`/nz/kit/bin/adm/tools/hostaekresume`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "/nz/kit.7.2.0.7/bin/adm/tools/hostaekresume" | awk '{sub(/.7.2.0.7/,"")}1'
/nz/kit/bin/adm/tools/hostaekresume
```

Comment: Guess I should have mentioned I don't know what will exist in the place of 7.2.0.7, so I can't search for that.  The only thing I know is it starts with "kit" and ends at the first "/".